# Explain this method of taking input in array

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; ++i)
{
    scanf("%d" , arr + i);
}
```

**explain this method of taking input in array.**

Generally, I try this method for entering elements in array.

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; ++i)
{
    scanf("%d" , &arr[i]);
}
```

**what is the difference between these two methods?**``
I found the former one used in competitive programming...

Comment: `arr + i`  is adding 2 thing together, `arr[i]` is picking element form array

Comment: In C, where `a` is any pointer or array type, `a + i` and `&a[i]` are equivalent by definition. It's just two ways of writing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "normal" way of using `scanf` to read `n` elements into an array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

Note well that I am calling

```
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

with an `&`, so that I pass a *pointer* to `array[i]`, so that `scanf` can fill in that element.  (One of the surprising things to remember about `scanf` is that you must always pass it pointers to fill in, unlike `printf`, where you pass values to print.)

But if we know how pointers and arrays and pointer arithmetic work, we can then see that this alternative form is equivalent:

```
    scanf("%d", arr + i);
```

The reason is that when when we mention the array `arr` in an expression like this, what we get is a pointer to the array's first element.  And then `arr + i` is a pointer to the array's `i`'th element, which is exactly what we want to pass to `scanf`, as before.

(Also, you'll notice that I have quietly changed your loop from `i = 1; i <= n` to `i = 0; i < n`.  Arrays in C are 0-based, so you always want your subscripts to run from 0 to n-1, not from 1 to n.)

Comment: @PadamPrakash Please refrain from making such a request.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, the second is **wrong** while the first one is **correct** - but even then the first one is **not robust** in that - it doesn't check the return value of `scanf()`.

`scanf()`'s `%d` format specifier expects an address of `int` variable. In the second case you provided the `int` variable itself (if you enabled compiler warnings this would generate warning message) and the first case you provided the address which results in correct behavior.

In case there are `n` elements then both of the `scanf()` would invoke Undefined Behavior because you are accessing an array index out of bound. (Arrays indexing starts from `0` in `C`).

`scanf("%d" , arr + i);` is equivalent to `scanf("%d",&arr[i])`. And the correct way to use `scanf()` would be

```
if( scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1){
   // error occured. Handle it.
}
```

---

Also from [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4):

> `d`
>   Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtol` function with the value `10` for the base argument. *The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer.*

To be clear on why both are same:-

The `arr+i` `arr` converted to pointer to the first element and then with that pointer we add `i` - in pointer arithmetic every addition is being directed by the type of element it points to. Here the array is containing `int` elements - which is why `arr+i` will point to the `i` th element of the array. `arr+i` is a pointer to the `i`th element which is what is expected by `%d` format specifier of `scanf`.

Also `&arr[i]` - here `&` address of operator returns the address of the element `arr[i]` or `*(arr+i)` which is nothing but the address of the i-th element that is what is being expected by `%d` format specifier of `scanf`.

Comment: @EugeneSh..; That's why added.. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: It's the difference between referring to a value and replacing it with input from the user, and referring to a point in memory and writing to it directly.

In C arrays referring to the name of the variable returns the address of that variable in memory.

The scanf() statement takes input from the user and writes it to a specific point in memory. Applying your second method (the one you are using) you should write something like this:

```
//YOUR EXAMPLE
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 3

int main()
{
    int arr[n];
    int i;
    printf("Input 3 numbers:\n");

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        scanf("%d" , &arr[i]);

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
```

Here you tell your program to get the value of the array in position i, symbolized by arr[i], and replace that value with the new value obtained from the user.

The other example:

```
//OTHER METHOD
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 3

int main()
{
    int arr[n];
    int i;
    printf("Input 3 numbers:\n");

for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    scanf("%d" , arr + i);

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
```

Here we reference the array by name, meaning we reference to the address of the starting point of where that array is stored in memory. In which case, we do not need the '&' symbol, as we are referring an address directly. The '+ i' term means that every iteration of the loop we refer to the next address in memory in that array (skipping sizeof(int) bytes), and so we write directly to that address.

I don't know for sure which is faster, perhaps these are even equivalent to the compiler, perhaps someone else here would have insights, but both ways would work.

NOTE:
I replaced your for loop boundaries, as you were looping from i=1 to i<=n, and writing to arr[i], which means you weren't utilizing the first element of the array, arr[0], and were out of bounds on arr[n]. (The last cell in the array is arr[n-1].

Comment: `arr + i -1`? When `i` is 0, that would be pointing to before the start of `arr`...you forgot to change this when you changed the loop boundaries?

Comment: Yes, I did! Thank you for noticing, I'll edit it out

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the argument corresponding to `%d` in a `scanf` call must be an expression of type `int *` (pointer to `int`).  Normally, you'd read an array element as

```
scanf( "%d", &arr[i] );
```

The *expression* `&arr[i]` evaluates to the address of the element, and it has type `int *`.

The array subscript operation `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)` - given a starting address `arr`, offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result.

This works because in C, an array expression that isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators is converted ("decays") from type "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.

Thus, the expression `arr` by itself will ultimately have type `int *`, and will evaluate to the address of the first element in the array:

```
arr == (arr + 0) == &arr[0]
```

Thus, if

```
*(arr + i) ==  arr[i] // int
```

then it follows that

```
  arr + i  == &arr[i] // int *
```

And this is why

```
scanf( "%d", arr + i );
```

works as well as

```
scanf( "%d", &arr[i] );
```

As a matter of style, use array subscript notation rather than pointer arithmetic.  It conveys the intent more clearly.  And, you're less likely to make a mistake with multi-dimensional arrays -

```
scanf( "%d", &arr[i][j][k] );
```

is easier to write and understand than

```
scanf( "%d", *(*(arr + i) + j) + k );
```

Also, check the result of `scanf` - it will return the number of items successfully read and assigned, or EOF if end of file has been signaled or there's some kind of input error.